# Get Value Dynamic Textbox in C#

Tags: c#

I made dynamic textboxes and keep it List

```
private void ConvertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
  foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
  {
    if (item is TextBox)
     {
       TextBox txt = item as TextBox;
       textBoxes.Add(txt);                  
     }

  }        
}
```

I get all of textboxes value but i have a problem. For examples; if user add 3 label like (A,B,C) and add Textboxes for them like (labelA has 2,labelB has 3,labelC has 1) and textboxes get value like array (textboxes[0] has value).The problem is i dont know which label has which value.

I added Textbox just like this:

```
private void addNewTextbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button button = (Button)sender;
   List<TextBox> textBoxes = button.Tag as List<TextBox>;
   if (textBoxes == null)
      button.Tag = textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
   TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
   textBoxes.Add(textBox);
   textBox.Location = new Point(90 * textBoxes.Count, button.Top);
   textBox.Size = new Size(50, 50);
   this.Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

I try to show screen for example;

```
LabelA-->Textbox1 , Textbox2

</br>

labelB -->Textbox3

</br>

LabelC --> Textbox4 , Textbox5 , TextBox6
```

Comment: Can't you keep the text box list in the Labels' Tag property as well?

Comment: The source code is missing the logic for adding the labels. it would be better if you could provide it too.

Comment: i don't know how to do that

Comment: You could create your own Label class (deriving from your current Label), and implement all the logic you need. The List of TextBoxes would be a property of the Label, the add-Method can do whatever you want...

Comment: How do you add the "Label"s? You say, for LabelA there can be 1 or more text boxes. How do the users add that Labels?

Comment: Users enter a number and i create labels.For example:3 LabelA,LabelB,LabelC  and each labels have a button with them.when users click button ,textboxes are created.

Answer (score 0):

Every control that is added has a `Name` property. Use this property to link the different controls together. For example (and you should come up with your own naming convention), you could do this:

LabelA --> TextboxA1, TextboxA2

LabelB --> TextboxB1

LabelC --> TextboxC1, TextboxC2, TextboxC3

If you wish to have a more complete (i.e. complex) solution, you could:

1. Create your own control that inherits from `TextBox`
2. Add a property for the name of the associated `Label` control
3. Set this property when a new control is instantiated

Answer (score 0):

I am trying very hard to understand your question, I guess you are trying to link the user-created textboxes to specific labels? Forgive me if I am completely wrong. How about structure your code to something like this:

Note: Edited with OP's new code

```
    Dictionary<Int, List<TextBox>> label_Textboxes_Dict = new Dictionary<Int, List<TextBox>>();
    List<Label> labelArray = new List<Label>(); //I suggest use list as you don't know the array size beforehand

    void addLabel(int labelNumber)
    {
        int currentLabelArrayCount = labelArray.count; //So that users can add multiple times
        for (int i = currentLabelArrayCount; i < currentLabelArrayCount +labelNumber; i++)
        {
            labelArray.Add(new Label());
            labelArray[i].Text = states[i] + "-->";
            this.Controls.Add(labelArray[i]);
            labelArray[i].Top = 100 + i * 30;
            labelArray[i].Left = 10;
            labelArray[i].Width = 30;
            label_Textboxes_Dict.Add(i, new List<TextBox>());
        }
    }

    void addTextBoxForLabel(int labelNum)
    {
        TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
        TextBox t2 = new TextBox();
        //etc... 

        if (label_Textboxes_Dict.ContainsKey(labelNum))
        {
            label_Textboxes_Dict[labelNum].Add(t1);
            label_Textboxes_Dict[labelNum].Add(t2);
        }
    }

    void doSomethingForAllTextboxesOfLabel(int labelNum)
    {
        List<TextBox> listOfTextBoxes;

        if(label_Textboxes_Dict.TryGetValue(labelNum, out listOfTextBoxes))
        {
            foreach(TextBox tb in listOfTextBoxes)
            {
                //do your stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: İ Cant do that Because it isn't specific for each List<TextBox>
addTextBoxForLabel function only keep the last list<textbox> value . @interceptwind

Comment: @Otantik Sorry I don't understand. "label_Textboxes_Dict" kept the list of textboxes for each and every label. You can access a specific list of textboxs by inputing the labelNum. Eg. To access Label 3's textboxs, just use "List<Textboxes> list3 = label_Texboxes_Dict[3];" Isn't it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
        Label[] labelArray = new Label[10];



        for (int i = 0; i < labelNumber; i++)
        {

            labelArray[i] = new Label();

            labelArray[i].Text = states[i] + "-->";

            this.Controls.Add(labelArray[i]);

            labelArray[i].Top = 100 + i * 30;

            labelArray[i].Left = 10;

            labelArray[i].Width = 30;

        }
```

i did label-created just like this.labelnumber is how many label user wants.@interceptwind